# Dropping element into Draggable area causes dragged item to disappear or move

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When I drag an item and drop it onto a droppable area, the item will realign itself such that its lower left corner is at the mouse cursor. Note that I am dragging my item from the child of one sister element to the great-grandchild of another sister element, ultimately between two VERY different nested views in Backbone.

This is right before I drop my item:   ............. This is what happens once I drop my item:

[image: Item Dragged] ...[image: Item Dropped - realigns]

This is the code for my draggable item, in a Backbone View's render function:

```
   // JQ Draggable
   $('.stamp').draggable({
      revert: 'invalid',
      helper: 'clone',
      drag: function( event, ui ) {
        //Not using the drag function, should I?
      }
  });
```

This is the code for my droppable item:

```
      // JQUI Droppable
      $(this.el).droppable({
        accept: '.stamp',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone(false)
            .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
            .css({position:'absolute', left:event.offsetX, top:event.offsetY});
          $(this).append(newDiv);
        }
      })
```

My goal is that when the item is dropped I don't want the item to move. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Adrianne/9jsmaLhs) jsFiddle does exactly what I want my code to do, as evidenced by the API example.

However, when I applied the code above (jsFiddle) to my project the draggable item disappears when dropped.

This is right before I drop my item: ............. This is what happens once I drop my item:

[image: Item Dragged] .. [image: Item Dropped - Disappears]

I only altered the code for my droppable item:

```
    // JQ Droppable
      $(this.el).droppable({
        accept: '.stamp',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone(false)
          .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
          .css({position:'absolute', left: ui.offsetX, top: ui.offsetY});
          $(this).append(newDiv);
        }
      })
```

Ultimately, just changing the CSS from the `event.offset*` to `ui.offset*`.  Please also note that in the droppable div area, there is an SVG that takes up the majority of the div, along with two other divs.

Tracing the 'missing element using JQuery once releasing using the `stop:` on the draggable, it appears to be going to to the far left.

So going back to the droppable code, if we get rid of everything and just include the `droppable({...})` function with two attributes, one for what to `accept`, and one for the `drop` function, but in the `drop` function, we `append` in anything, instantiated or not, we get the expected results (although with a console error):

```
$('#droppable-area').droppable({
    accept: '.stamp',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('#droppable-area').append(n);
    }
})
```

but if we don't include the `append` or if we pass in no parameters in the `append`, it 'disappears', as seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/7ykaupz1/).

What is going on?

---

ALSO, when investigating the draggable element, when you grab it in the upper left, the `console.log(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);` will print something ~`5 5`.  If you grab it in the lower left , it will be the size of the button div, so in our case, ~`12 25`.  When you drag the item INTO the droppable div, but DO NOT release, the `eventX` and `eventY` change, to be the position of the cursor within the div.  Maybe I can take the initial value of `eventX` and `eventY` as soon as they start dragging and use that to adjust the exact `position:absolute`?

Comment: long question, wish the title was more elaborate

Answer (score 2):

You may need to have the draggable's position set manually cased on the ui object's position at time of drop, in relation to the droppable target.

```
// JQ Droppable
  $(this.el).droppable({
    accept: '.stamp',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $('<div class="btn stamp dropped"></div>')
        .text(ui.draggable.text())
        .appendTo(this)
        .css({position:"absolute", left:ui.offset.left-this.offsetLeft, top:ui.offset.top-this.offsetTop});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/7ykaupz1/) is that, the [`helper`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) element is created just for providing the visual feedback, and It will be removed once the drag is [stopped](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop).

Just grab a copy of it using the a [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone) method when it is [dropped](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop), and [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) it to droppable before it's removed from `DOM`, and you'll be fine.

```js
$('.stamp').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function (event, ui) {}
})

$('#droppable-area').droppable({
    accept: '.stamp',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
         $(this).append(ui.helper.clone());
    }

})
```

```css
.stamp {
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#draggable-items {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#droppable-area {
    clear: left;
    margin: 10px;
    widows: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable-items">Draggable items
    <div id="system-label-1" class="btn stamp">1</div>
    <div id="system-label-2" class="btn stamp">2</div>
    <div id="system-label-3" class="btn stamp">3</div>
    <div id="system-label-4" class="btn stamp">4</div>
</div>
<div id="droppable-area">Droppable Area</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem!
I found out that `helper: 'clone'` somehow doesn't work as expected.
remove that and tell me if it helps.

Comment: We need the `helper: 'clone'` though to allow for it to be a repeatable 'stamp' and be used over and over.  You are correct though, removing that will help.

Comment: insert ´revert: true´ then and try it again!